# Is there a way to change the MS Word 2013 "pick up where you left off" feature?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word-2013

This is an annoying feature. I scanned through all options but don't see any option to disable. Any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Is there a way to change the MS Word 2013 “pick up where you left off” feature?

Warning:

The instructions below contain steps that tell you how to modify the registry. However, serious problems might occur if you modify the registry incorrectly.

Therefore, make sure that you follow these steps carefully. For added protection, back up the registry before you modify it. Then, you can restore the registry if a problem occurs.

For more information see [How to back up and restore the registry in Windows.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322756)

---

#### Disable Pick Up Where You Left Off in Word

> When you close a document, Word automatically bookmarks your most recent position in the document. If you take a break from reading, when you reopen your document, you can pick up where you left off. If you are signed in to Office, Resume Reading works even if you reopen the document from a different computer or other device.
>
> If you feel that this feature is not useful for you, then you may want to disable it.
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> combination, type `Regedt32.exe` in Run dialog box and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open
>    the Registry Editor.
> 2. Navigate to the following location:
>
>    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Word\Reading Locations
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Here the Reading Locations key is the culprit and is responsible for arising the tip on every start up of Office components. If you
>    delete this key, it will help you to disable tip immediately. But as
>    soon as you reboot the machine, the key will be written by system
>    again and tip will start popping up. So we need to make this key
>    read-only for everyone so that it can’t be re-written by system. To
>    make this key read-only, right click over it and pick Permissions.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Click on Advanced in the above shown window. Now uncheck the option “Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable
>    permission entries from this object”.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. Click Apply followed by OK, again do the same for Permissions window. You may close the Registry Editor now, reboot to see results.

And a comment by another poster on the above:

> I think that in a more recent version of Word, the "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object" box is unchecked by default, and you have to check "deny" Full Control to SYSTEM in the Permissions window before it will work.

Source [Disable Pick Up Where You Left Off in Word](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off-office)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill, I'll try this. It seems MS hasn't provided any way to disable this, so need to use the workaround, is it?

Comment: @user2981854 Correct, that's why you need the workaround.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would someone want to disable this?

Comment: @anon The OP said it was "annoying" ;)

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but wanted to describe my issue with the feature: Unfortunately the little balloon tip that pops up takes focus, which means that I actually have to dismiss it before I can press Ctrl+F to find something. With the work I'm doing at the moment, it's quite annoying. Redmond should have created an option to disable it. Not sure if its the same in Office 2016...

Comment: @MikeRockett The answer shows you exactly how to turn it off (disable it).

Comment: @DavidPostill - yeah, have done that. Just elaborating on my experience.

Comment: The approach given in this answer [does not work](https://superuser.com/q/1704192/156554) in Office 365 / Windows 10. And yes, @MikeRockétt is perfectly correct. This little annoying "left off" thing prevents me from quickly opening a document and do searching. I now have to wait 3-5 seconds after opening any doc, before I can start searching it. Veeeeery annoing.

Answer (score 2):

A programmatic way to dismiss the Welcome Back panel is to put this code in your Normal.dotm file:

```
    Sub AutoOpen()
        Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory, Extend:=wdMove
    End Sub
```

This code moves the cursor to the bottom of the document and then back up to the top.

If you’d rather not fiddle with VBA macros, then I’ve also put this capability into an Add-In.  You can configure the add-in to dismiss the Welcome Back panel, and also to force documents to open in Draft View mode (or any other view of your choice); which restores functionality that MS removed in Word 2013.  The add-in can be downloaded from:
    http://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/Word/ViewMgr_v2.1.zip

Comment: LIFESAVER! This is exactly what I was looking for! Thousand kudos! :) I didn't want to mess up with the macro, so I used your ViewMgr. The installation instruction must be updated a little bit to cover newest Office 365, but the most important thing is that it WORKS! You rock, man!

Comment: @trejder I'm glad it worked for you.  BTW, I've posted a newer version here: https://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/Word/ViewMgr_v3.0.zip

Answer (score 1):

Make two VBA macros for Word.

First:

```
Sub BookmarkSave ()  
'  
' Set Bookmark and Save  
'  
    ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add Name:="OpenAt"  
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="OpenAt"  
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.SmallScroll Up:=6  
    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="OpenAt"  
    ActiveWindow.ActivePane.SmallScroll Down:=2  
    ActiveDocument.Save  
End Sub
```

And second:

```
Sub AutoOpen()  
   If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("OpenAt") = True Then  
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="OpenAt"  
   ActiveWindow.ActivePane.SmallScroll Up:=6  
   Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="OpenAt"  
   ActiveWindow.ActivePane.SmallScroll Down:=2  
End Sub
```

After saving a document with macro BookmarkSave this document will  reopen where you closed it without showing “Pick up where you left off” or “Welcome back”.