# Disable "Pick up where you left off" in Word 365

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, microsoft-word-365

**tl;dr** *The "Pick up where you left off" feature is useless and annoying, but all guides, that I went through to disable it, doesn't seems to work in Word 365 Version 2111 / Windows 10 Pro that I have. What else can I try?*

---

First, I've tried the regular way (as described in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/894111/156554) or [here](https://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/how-to-disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off-in-ms-word/), [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/436233/how-to-disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off-in-microsoft-office/) and [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off-office)):

- Open `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Reading Locations` in Regedit
- Right-click and select *Permissions…* from context menu, click *Advanced* button
- The *Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object* checkbox was already unchecked so I expected that this solution won't work, but I continued the solution

I've restarted the computer and, as expected, the nasty popup was still there.

Next, I've tried the [a bit different approach](https://onezeronull.com/2022/01/05/disable-pick-up-where-you-left-off-in-word/) and in addition to above steps, I have also:

- Selected *Account Unknown (something)* item in the users / groups list
- Revoked reading rights by checking a checkbox for *Full Control* row and *Deny* column
- Did the same for *RESTRICTED* and *SYSTEM* users
- This time check the *Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object* checkbox to enforce that all child folders will inherit *Deny* setting on *Read* flag for all above mentioned users from current object.

Again, I've restarted the computer and, again, no effect. What am I missing?

I have Office 365:

[image]

Version 2111:

[image]

I am running on Windows 10 Pr (Version  10.0.19042 Build 19042).

What other steps should I undertake in order to get rid of this nasty little thing which prevents me from quickly searching each newly opened Word document?

Comment: Maybe you should deny Full Control also to your own account, as Word is running under it.

Comment: Tried that. Can't. No permissions ("_Unable to save permissions changes on Reading Locations. Access is denied_"). Meaning, I can set it for the user / account / group itself, but any attempt of using "Advanced" dialog to propagate these "downward" to all child nodes ends with the above mentioned error. I am on admin account, running Regedit as an admin and I can't set permissions for my very own user. How Microsoft-typical...

Comment: You could perhaps create another admin account and do it from there.

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) for which the Windows Registry solution doesn't work (description in question and [here](https://superuser.com/a/894111/156554)) there are at least two options:

- Add a special macro to *Normal.dotm* template (source: [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1219437/156554))
- Install and use the [ViewMgr 3.0](https://rath.ca/Misc/VBA/Word/ViewMgr_v3.0.zip) Word add-in (source: [this blog post](https://onezeronull.com/2022/02/15/get-rid-of-pick-up-where-you-left-off-from-word-three-methods/) and the above mentioned [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1219437/156554))

*Disclaimer: I am **not** the author of this add-in. I only love it!*

Answer (score 1):

The following is like breaking a butterfly on a wheel. But it might help.

```
reg delete "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Reading Locations" /f
```

At least until the next use of Word.

Word will create the key `Reading Locations` again. But only with new documents.

Additionally you can use brute force and schedule the previous in a task with e.g. `schtasks`. Or less invasive as `Autostart` script.